# how can I show a div based on content in another div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs in html such:

```
<div class="litter"> 
    <div class="litter-1">
        <div class="status">Available</div> 
        <div class="available"><img /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="litter-2">
        <div class="status">Available</div> 
        <div class="available"><img /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The status text will vary based on user input. If the status is available the available class should not show. But if the status is unavailable then it should. The image is present all the time but only displaying if the status changes.

I can get the jQuery to either hide all of the images, or show them all, but not based on the html value of the status.

jQuery

```
if($('.litter > .status').html()==="Available") {
    $(this).next('.available').hide();
    } else {
    $('.available').show();
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Haldo put me on the right track, but in order to make it all come together with the string. Instead of `if ($(this).text() === ("Available")` I had to use this `if ($(this).text().indexOf('Needs a Forever Home') > -1)`

The rest of the code stays the same as Haldo's.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop using jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
// change selector to '.litter .status'
$('.litter .status').each(function() {
    // loop through each .status element 

    // get partner img container .available
    var imgContainer = $(this).parent().find('.available');

    if ($(this).text() === "Available")
    {
        imgContainer.hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        imgContainer.show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="litter"> 
    <div class="litter-1">
        <div class="status">Available</div> 
        <div class="available"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="placeholder1" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="litter-2">
        <div class="status">Other status</div> 
        <div class="available"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="placeholder2" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works. The if statement isn't doing it's work. But if I use imgContainer.addClass('test') between the var and the if statement. The class is added. The same test fails in the if statement. Any ideas why?

Comment: You can see that it works from the code snippet - the first image is hidden.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'the if statement isn't doing it's work'. Why are you now adding `imgContainer.addClass('test')`? Is that part of your requirements? Adding `imgContainer.addClass('test')` before the `if` does not seem to affect the results in my testing.

Comment: Yes the code snippet works. The reason I was doing addClass was for testing only. Since the images were still all showing I wanted to see whether I had the syntax correct. And the class is added if I add that before this if statement, but inside that it doesn't add any class.

Comment: `imgContainer` is the `<div class="available">` element.  I've tested adding `imgContainer.addClass('test')` inside the `if` or `else` and this results in  `<div class="available test">` (ie the class `test` has been added to the imgContainer element).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: If the images are still showing you could try hiding the actual `img` element. `var img = $(this).parent().find('.available img');` then doing `img.hide()/img.show()` in the `if`. Not sure if that would resolve the issue though.  It might be worth posting a new question.

Comment: Just figured something out. I simplified my code in the example. I'm actually looking for a string. if ($(this).text() === ("Needs a Forever Home")  This never returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a single class, `status-available`, and combine it with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to control the display of the image.

```html
<!-- Image will show -->
<div class="status status-available">…</div>
```

vs.

```html
<!-- Image will not show -->
<div class="status">…</div>
```

**Example**

```css
/* Image is hidden by default */
.available > img {
  display: none;
}

 /* Adjacent sibling combinator in action */
.status-available + .available > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="litter">
  <div class="litter-1">
    <div class="status status-available">Available</div>
    <div class="available">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="Cute cat" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="litter-2">
    <div class="status">Available</div>
    <div class="available">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="Cute cat" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```